# SQL return values of affected rows in last query?

Tags: php, sql, return-value, resultset

I have an SQL query which inserts a new record into `table1`. The records 'id' is the PK (`field1`) and has the auto increment property:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field2, field3) VALUES ("Hello", "World")
```

My next query (immediately afterwards) inserts a record into `table2`, and requires the id of the row which was affected in the previous query.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (field2) VALUES (PKValueOfAffectedRowInPreviousQuery)
```

Is there a function which can return a result set for the rows affected in a query, something along the lines of `$result = $stmt->return_affected_records()` so that I could access this `field1` value?

This is entirely different to returning the *number* of affected rows, which I know is received using `$stmt->affected_rows`. I'm concerned with the *values* within those records affected.

Comment: Depending on your flavour of Database/Interface, [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this with a `select` in between these two `insert`s:

```
$value1 = "Hello";
$value2 = "World";

INSERT INTO table1 (field2, field3) VALUES ($value1,$value2);

$sql = "SELECT field1 FROM table1 WHERE field2 ='" . $value1 . "' AND field3 = '" . $value2 . "'";
```

Now you just have to extract the `id` from the result and make your second insert.

Comment: Ouch!!!! Hasn't anybody heard of [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)?

Comment: @MarkBaker Nope :/